# (flex mobile)how to add element in the my custom layout

Tags: apache-flex, layout, mobile

this is my code:

```
public class my_Layout extends LayoutBase
{
    public function my_Layout(){
        super();
        var b:Button = new Button;
        b.label="my button"
        addChild(b)
    }
}
```

but it show error ,  i the method addChild is undefined ,

so waht can i do ,  thanks

Comment: You're not supposed to add elements in a Layout class. You add elements to a component (custom or not) and you position and size these elements through your Layout class.

Comment: I think @RIAstar nailed it.  Layouts are really just an "outsourcing" of the measure() method and portions of the updateDisplayList() that size and position children.  You wouldn't add a child directly tot he layout, but rather the component which is using the layout.  I Forget how to access that component from within the layout class.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com That's the `target` property (which is a GroupBase) of the `LayoutBase` class.

Comment: just use addElement instead of addChild if you are using a spark component.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function get_list():List{
        var list:List = target.parent.parent.parent.parent as List;
        return list;
    }
    private function get_document():View{
        var list:List = get_list();
        return list.document as View;
    }

var list:List = get_list();
        var document:View = get_document();
        var b:Button = new Button;
        b.label = 'wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww';
        document.addElement(b);
```